# LLDB source command file

Tags: osx-mavericks, lldb

I have an lldb command file with the following text:

```
    settings set -- auto-confirm true 
    breakpoint set --name main
    process launch
    continue
    quit
```

I'm trying to source a command file with the command:

```
    lldb --source lldb_start_single_step program
```

However, I'm getting this output:

```
    Executing commands in 'lldb_start_single_step'.
    (lldb)  settings set -- auto-confirm true 
    ' failed with error: invalid boolean string value: 'true ttings set -- auto-confirm true 
    Current executable set to 'program' (x86_64).
```

I've tried searching for a solution but I can't seem to find anything, as lldb still doesn't seem to have much documentation yet.

Comment: I should note that I can run the 'settings set -- auto-confirm true' command manually just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was using vim and it was set to give dos line endings and they needed to be converted to unix.

Anyone who has the same problem can refer to http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/File_format